# docker-compose output format has changed to long, how to get back short output?

Tags: command-line, docker-compose

Output of `docker compose ps` command in docker compose version v2.20.x and earlier was short, since "COMMAND" column was truncated:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin=2.20.*
[...]

$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.20.2

$ docker compose ps postgres
NAME                 IMAGE                              COMMAND                  SERVICE             CREATED             STATUS                 PORTS
xxxxxxxxx-postgres   xxxxxxxxx-postgres:yyyyyyyyyyyyy   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   postgres            2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks (healthy)   127.0.0.1:9432->5432/tcp
```

But since docker compose version v2.21.x and newer, output of `docker compose ps` command become long, because "COMMAND" column not truncated:

```
$ sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin=2.21.*
[...]

$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.21.0

$ docker compose ps postgres
NAME                 IMAGE                              COMMAND
                 SERVICE    CREATED       STATUS                 PORTS
xxxxxxxxx-postgres   xxxxxxxxx-postgres:yyyyyyyyyyyyy   "docker-entrypoint.sh postgres -c tcp_keepalives_idle=600 -c shared_preload_libraries=pg_stat_statements,pg_cron -c cron.database_na
me=nnnnnnnnnn"   postgres   2 weeks ago   Up 2 weeks (healthy)   127.0.0.1:9432->5432/tcp
```

This is confusing and doesn't fit in console window at 1920x1080 monitor. Columns wrap to the next row, and this output becomes painful to read.

Is there an option to force docker-compose use old-style truncated short output format?